# Is $\mathbb Q_p(a_2)=\mathbb Q_p(b_2)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$.

Suppose $a_1,b_1$ be two algebraic numbers of $\mathbb Q_p$ such that $\mathbb Q_p(a_1)=\mathbb Q_p(b_1).$

Now let $a_2, b_2$ are algebraic numbers of $\mathbb Q_p(a_1)$ or $\mathbb Q_p(b_1)$ such that
\begin{align}
&\mathbb Q_p(a_2) \subset \mathbb Q_p(a_1,b_2) \\
& \mathbb Q_p(b_2) \subset \mathbb Q_p(b_1,a_2)
\end{align}

> Can we say $\mathbb Q_p(a_2)=\mathbb Q_p(b_2)$ ?

---

I think if $a_1,b_1$ are $n^{th}$ roots of $-1$, then the answer is yes.

In the other cases, I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Take $p=3,a_1=a_2=b_1=\sqrt{-1},b_2=1$

Comment: @reuns, when would it hold ? Suppose $a_1,b_1$ are $n$-th roots of $-p$ and $a_2,b_2$ are $m$-th roots of $-p$, with $m>n$, is there any affirmative answer?

Comment: No try with $p=3,a_1=b_1=(-3)^{1/2},a_2=(-3)^{1/3},b_2=(-3)^{1/6}$

Comment: @reuns, suppose $a_1 \neq a_2$ and $b_1  \neq b_2$. And $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2 \neq 1$. I didn't find an example against my conclusion.  Can you please comment on this?